# In PHP what's an easy way to do performance logs of your application?

Tags: php, performance, logging

My application is going very slow on the production server (where I don't control the PHP/apache to install a debugger/profiler) so I want to add a performance monitoring library to my project to see what's taking so much time to process.

Ideally I want something that I just add to my project and it starts logging all function calls and the time they took (but I don't know if that's possible without a profiler installed on the PHP server).

In the worst case I want a benchmark / performance log library to easily do stuff like:

```
benchmark_start("web service call");
benchmark_end(); // prints the time it took
```

I'm fully aware this is a simple class to do just using microtime. I'm just wondering if there are "more powerful" libraries out there for this.

Comment: The symfony debug toolbar in version 1.x did this, and it was very good - lots of standard events/database calls plus their timings, and custom ones can be added too. I've not used Symfony2.1, but a quick search shows that this too has a debug bar.

Comment: Ah, you mention a framework - but do you just want a library that can do this in your existing project? If so, consider the one from 1.x that was ported to a standalone project: http://www.php-debug.com/

Comment: Please answer the question with php-debug.com because that seems a good library for my needs. I'll just wait for more suggestions before choosing the accepted answer :)

Comment: Does it only perform so bad on the production server or also on the development / staging machine?

Comment: I really don't understand the closing. Asking for a list of debug/benchmark libraries isn't allowed? I can give multiple examples of similar Q&A done in stackoverflow like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341154/php-logging-framework?rq=1

Comment: I guess it was because it was discursive, and thus there is no concept of a 'best' answer. I thought it was edge-case enough to save it from closing, but I guess not everyone thought that way! Were you looking for more answers?

Comment: Yeah, php-debug seems like a good solution but it looks abandoned so I was wondering if there were more alternatives to it. Still, it is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 1.x (now superceded by a new major version - 2.1 at the time of writing) offered a debug toolbar that creates a JavaScript-based clickable widget listing various log events, database calls and PHP configuration detail.

If you don't want to switch to a full new framework, try [PHP Debug](http://php-debug.com) - it is essentially the debug toolbar from 1.x, ported to a standalone project. I don't think it gets much in the way of development these days, but it may still be worth a go.